# Excel 2013 code generates "Path not found" error in Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code from Excel 2013 that used to work.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

I changed to a computer with Excel 365 installed.

I will get the errors:

> Path not found: '\VBA3CD.tmp'
>   400

The VBA3CD.tmp filename will differ every time. I've already "enable all macros" in Excel's security settings.

I've tried different varieties of the same thing, for example:

```
Set wsTemplate = Sheets("Template")
wsTemplate.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

Getting the same "Path not found" error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really getting an error about being unable to do something with the file system from the single VBA command to copy a worksheet - which obviously doesn't touch the file system, it's all in-memory - then something about that worksheet is probably trying to run vba code.

I just checked and when one copies a worksheet, the copy runs the WORKSHEET_CALCULATE and WORKSHEET_ACTIVATE events.  It may be that one of these events or another are running code that needs that path.   You just have to check the VBA code for the sheet being copied - does it have any Worksheet_  subroutines?

Comment: Thanks Roy.  I've found the root problem, but still can't solve it -- it's not the VBA code.  I re-started with a fresh Excel, copied my Worksheets over without any VBA code -- I can copy sheets fine (manually, that is).  As soon as I add a VBA Module, even though the Module is blank!,  the "Path not found" error comes up.  Then, I tried with fresh blank Excel Worksheet + add a Module, no more error.  So, there must be something in my Worksheet that's causing the problem???

Comment: OK I figured out a workaround.  This almost definitely have something to do with some security setting in Windows or Office 365.  I still can't fix it.

The workaround is run Excel as Administrator ....